# is there a limit on how many input tags can be used in razor pages

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to have an edit page that changes company / location name on button click
I am using the following code to store the selected data in case validation fails:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Data.Locations.Count; i++)
    {
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Data.Locations[i].Id" name="LocationId(@i)"/>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Data.Locations[i].Name" name="LocationName(@i)"/>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Data.Locations[i].CompanyId" name="LocationCompId(@i)"/>
    }
```

This is causing an error 400 request, all the values seem to go in there.
The strangest thing about it is that if I use any two of these input tags the value is pulled out correctly, it only doesnt work when all 3 are put in there.
The companyId input is a foreign key for the following DTO:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Data.Companies.Count; i++)
    {
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Data.Companies[i].Id" name="CompanyId(@i)"/>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Data.Companies[i].Name" name="CompanyName(@i)"/>
    }
```

The c# DTOs are laid out like this:

```
public List<CompanyDto> Companies { get; init; }
public List<LocationDto> Locations { get; init; }
           

            public record CompanyDto
            {
                public int Id { get; init; }
                public string Name { get; init; }
            }

            public record LocationDto
            {
                public int Id { get; init; }
                public string Name { get; init; }
                public int CompanyId { get; init; }
            }
```

Comment: Can you show your action parameters? Your name attributes are probably not correct.

Comment: 400 error is likely to be either a missing anti-forgery token. Or a GET url that's too long, in which case you could POST the form.

Comment: Though maybe you should consider serialising data as json...

Answer (score 0):

.net core bind data with `name` attribute,and asp-for will generate html with `id` and `name`,you can remove the `name` attribute in your code(The format of your name is wrong).Here is a demo to pass data from view to handler:

```
public class Data
    {
        public List<CompanyDto> Companies { get; set; }
        public List<LocationDto> Locations { get; set; }
    }
```

cshtml.cs:

```
[BindProperty]
        public Data Data { get; set; } = new Data();
        public void OnGet()
        {
            Data.Companies= new List<CompanyDto> { new CompanyDto { Id = 1, Name = "c1" }, new CompanyDto { Id = 2, Name = "c2" }, new CompanyDto { Id = 3, Name = "c3" } };
            Data.Locations = new List<LocationDto> { new LocationDto { Id = 11, CompanyId = 1, Name = "l1" }, new LocationDto { Id = 22, CompanyId = 2, Name = "l2" }, new LocationDto { Id = 33, CompanyId = 3, Name = "l3" } };
        }
        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            return Page();
        }
```

cshtml:

```
<form method="post">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Data.Locations.Count; i++)
    {
        <input asp-for="Data.Locations[i].Id" />
        <input asp-for="Data.Locations[i].Name" />
        <input asp-for="Data.Locations[i].CompanyId" />
    }
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Data.Companies.Count; i++)
    {
        <input asp-for="Data.Companies[i].Id" />
        <input asp-for="Data.Companies[i].Name" />
    }
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

result:
[image]